# Playwright - stored auth state, expiry

Tags: playwright

As per the examples [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#basic-shared-account-in-all-tests) I have set up shared auth state for my tests which run before each of our main projects. Currently however I am not clear on what happens if parts of our auth state expire, for whatever reason our system has a 5 minute timeout and so we are going to run into this issue very soon. Will playwright automatically get new auth state? Do I need to create a mechanism to renew auth state somehow?

Comment: You'll probably need to renew the auth on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, timeout implies the application is idle, when no tests are running and system is idle for 5mins then timeout happens and storage state not come into picture.

A Case where tests are running, so system isn't idle at that time there wont be a timeout at all.  so it wont hamper the test execution unless and untill there is pause in execution for 5mins.